# Ошибка: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Tags: android, sha256, sha1

Пытаюсь получить SHA-1 и SHA-256 для приложения (раньше всё без проблем получалось), при помощи команды:
keytool -alias <myAlias> -keystore <path-to-keystore> -list -v

Предлагается ввести пароль для keystore...Ввожу пароль (пароль и элиас верные), пробовал на разных приложениях.
В ответ выдаётся ошибка:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:663)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:941)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:379)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:372)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?